# QGIS: Animation base on a trajectory/LinestringM

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I am trying to apply the same technique as described in this excellent post, using the Time Manager plugin on a trajectory (LinestringM): https://anitagraser.com/2017/08/14/movement-data-in-gis-7-animated-trajectories-with-timemanager/

After spending quite some time investigating, I can’t  make this fully work as in the article.

I am able to animate the trajectory if I only use one « layer » of  Geometry Generator

1. Geometry Generator as: segments_to_lines($geometry)
2. then a Simple line » with a programmatic Stroke Width:

```
    CASE
    WHEN
    (
    m(start_point(geometry_n($geometry,@geometry_part_num))) <( second(age(animation_datetime(),to_datetime('1970-01-01 00:00'))))
    and m(end_point(geometry_n($geometry,@geometry_part_num))) >( second(age(animation_datetime(),to_datetime('1970-01-01 00:00'))))
    )
    THEN

    2+1 ELSE 0.001

    END
```

Similar approach with Points works as well, I can also display Symbols based the M value of each individual Point and the current animation datetime.

However I want to interpolate a Point along the lines based on the animation_datetime() to provide a smoother rendering and a better time resolution, as described in the reference post.

As soon as I add a second Geometry Generator layer, I cannot get anything to be displayed

My $geometry is:

```
'LineStringM (2.3501 45.5036 1763490232, 2.3572 45.5088 176… etc...'
```

I have tried the provided sample code as the second layer of Geometry Generator:

```
CASE
WHEN (
m(end_point(geometry_n($geometry,@geometry_part_num)))
> second(age(animation_datetime(),to_datetime('1970-01-01 00:00')))
AND
m(start_point(geometry_n($geometry,@geometry_part_num)))
<= second(age(animation_datetime(),to_datetime('1970-01-01 00:00')))
)
THEN
line_interpolate_point(
  geometry_n($geometry,@geometry_part_num),
  1.0 * (
    second(age(animation_datetime(),to_datetime('1970-01-01 00:00')))
    - m(start_point(geometry_n($geometry,@geometry_part_num)))
  ) / (
    m(end_point(geometry_n($geometry,@geometry_part_num)))
    - m(start_point(geometry_n($geometry,@geometry_part_num)))
  )
  * length(geometry_n($geometry,@geometry_part_num))
)
END
```

but nothing is shown and the editor shows Null as an output

I tested other combinations as :

```
m(start_point(geometry_n(segments_to_lines($geometry),@geometry_part_num)))
```

or :

```
 m(start_point(segments_to_lines($geometry)))
```

I also set the CASE to always be true, or spent some time only working on the CASE part

But when dealing with this second layer of geometry generator, even by inspecting variables in the editor I can’t figure out how this is expected to work and how the different geometry layers and variables actually cascade.

What is going on?

Comment: I did not find a suitable answer to my own question above (which in short relates to how multiplart geometry cascade down multiple layers of Geometry Generator). I however worked around the issue by interpolating the Point along the whole line which is enough for my use case even if not 100% percent accurate. I also transitioned to the integrated Temporal controller.